# $T(z) e^{-\partial_z} $ for Yangian is a Manin matrix

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $T(u)$ be the generating matrix of the Yangian $Y(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. So we have the identity $[T_{ij}(u),T_{kl}(v)]=\frac{1}{u-v}(T_{kj}(u)T_{il}(v)-T_{kj}(v)T_{il}(u))$.

We can consider the matrix $T(z)e^{-\partial_z}$. It is written in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.2236.pdf#page12 that this matrix is Manin matrix (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manin_matrix) but the proof is not given.

Question: how to prove this fact?

Comment: think you should ask on MathOverflow

Comment: Actually I realised that the proof is rather easy. You just need to use RTT=TTR relation many times.